# How do I really change my login email address?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

Fortunately, I can still login with this email address that I have lost access to.  I have been searching around here for a way to update it to the current one I use.  I have found many answers.  But they all give instructions to click on something not displayed or in one case, a page that prompts me to login via another email I no longer have the password for.

I need current *up to date* instructions on how to change my email address or add another email-based login for this same user name that I am posting this with.

Answer (score 6):

To change your login email address, you first need to add a new login and then remove the previous one from the "remove" option (shown in the image below).

To add a new login, go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current and then select "add more logins...".

You can also reach this option by clicking "Edit Profile & Settings" at the top of your profile page and then selecting "My Logins" from the side.

[image]

After performing the above steps, you will see something like this:
[image]

Here, you can link an already existing Google account or add a new email with a new password to the existing account.

Now you would be able to login with the new email and may remove the initial email as shown in the first image.

Comment: Downvoted for answering a duplicate question.

Comment: @Luuklag aren't votes supposed to be anonymous?  And if you downvoted every answer on a duplicate question, you'd lose about 30 rep.

Comment: They are but I chose not to this time @Ollie. Education comes at a cost ;)

Comment: This question came up result #2 when googling "stackexchange change user email", so it helped - as did the linked active question.