# Can i change the email of my SE account ? If yes, how?

Tags: support, email-addresses

I want to use a different email address with my account. Is this possible  ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350366/771581

Comment: go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current and change it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the [edit email settings page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) and change your email address at the top.