# How do I delete my Stack Exchange OpenID account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I wanted to change my Stack Exchange mail address and just went through the **absolute madness** described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247605/how-can-i-change-my-stack-exchange-login-email/247606#247606) - only to find out that I've now created *another* useless account that I cannot delete.

How can I delete the newly created [OpenID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) account and does the deletion affect the Stack Exchange accounts in any way?

Comment: To change your email address, you can see this more up to date [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350366/771581).

Answer (score 4):

From the [contact](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) page:

> If you need to delete your account, merge accounts, or have an issue that can't be addressed by meta, please use the form below.

So go to the page; in the "Describe Problem" form, say you want to delete your OpenID account.  Be specific, and give them the email address the OpenID account is associated with.  The deletion of the OpenID account shouldn't affect your other accounts.